# Can't see "Domain Service Class" item in silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am binding data in silverlight using WCF RIA Services. I need to add new item "Domain Service Class".

Right Click - Solution.Web - Add New Item. But i could not find Domain Service Class. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Normally are new classes are added to projects and not solutions.

Comment: @Jehof Yeah that is a project..

Comment: do you have the WCF RIA services toolkit installed?

Comment: please install a Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio. There should be a RIA service tools and other components and libraries